# Как задать android:layout_marginLeft, android:layout_marginStart кнопке через код?

Tags: java, android, xml

У меня есть динамически-создаваемая кнопка. Мне нужно чтобы после ее создания она была после определенного элемента. В xml я делал это так:

```
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/tvName"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvName"
```

А как задать layout_alignLeft и layout_alignStar с помощью кода, например, в MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Программно это делается вот так:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
lp.leftMargin = (int) (yourMargin*getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
    //или
lp.setMarginStart((int) (yourMargin*getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity));
button.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

`RelativeLayout.` замените на тип вашего контейнера-родителя.

`scaledDensity` - для корректного отображения на экранах с разными dpi

UPD: Для определения взаиморасположения элементов в `RelativeLayout` делайте, например, так:

```
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,firstView);
```

(либо другой `addRule(...)`)

Comment: Как я понял, это позволяет задать отступы в dp? Возможно, я указал не то свойство. Можно ли программно задать порядок расположения view-элементов на экране? Т.е. если есть два TextView,  то чтобы второй, к примеру, располагался под первым?

Comment: да, в dp. Если вы имели ввиду относительное расположение в `RelativeLayout`, посмотрите обновленный ответ

Comment: Спасибо! А нет ли подобного для ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Сделайте переменную `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp` и через `lp.` посмотрите, там много возможностей. Сам не разбирался.